# Search in sub sets of set which are lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given:

```
list = [{'a','b'},{'c','d'}]
```

and I want to know if 'a' is in the list.

should I first unpack the list as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321915/python-unpacking-the-lists-and-sets) to new_list and the use 'a' in new_list

Or is there a shorter way (without importing modules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
spam = [{'a','b'},{'c','d'}]
eggs = [{'d','b'},{'c','d'}]

print(any('a' in my_set for my_set in spam))
print(any('a' in my_set for my_set in eggs))
```

Output

```
True
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `any`.

**Ex:**

```
l = [{'a','b'},{'c','d'}]
print( any(map(lambda x: "a" in x, l)) )
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's solve it. I write it on a function to use "return" keyword

```
def a_is_there():

    lists = [{'a','b'},{'c','d'}]
    for list in lists:
        if "a" in list:
            print("True")
            return True
    print("False")
    return False


a_is_there()
```

Thanks